Equality on $\partial\Omega$ of weak sub-/super-solution implies weak solution
Assume that $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ denotes some bounded domain. Further, let $f_1$ resp. $f_2$ be a weak solution to the stationary $p$-Laplace equation
$$-\Delta_p u = 0 \qquad\mbox{in $E$}.$$
It is well known that, assuming $f_1 \leq f_2$ a.e. on $\partial E$, that the comparison principles implies that $f_1\leq f_2$ a.e. in $E$. However, by plugging in the test function $(f_1-f_2)_+$ in the weak formulation and subtract the weak forms from each other, we easily deduce that $f_1=f_2 + C$ a.e. in $E$ for some constant $C$. But now, provided that $f_1=f_2$ a.e. in $\partial E$, this should imply that $f_1=f_2$ a.e. in $E$, and thus $f_1=f_2$ would actually be a weak solution (not only a sub-/super-solution!) to the equation! This seems to be a bit suprising. I am wondering whether my reasoning is actually correct? Thanks for any input!
